# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable when using defaultdict

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Why is `vocabulary[feature]` throwing `'int' object is not callable.` Kindly help?

Here is the code:

```
vocabulary = defaultdict(None)
vocabulary.default_factory = vocabulary.__len__()
j_indices = []
analyzed = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'quux']
for feature in analyzed:
   j = vocabulary[feature]
   print('%s %d' % (feature, j))
   j_indices.append(j)
```

Comment: Please post the entire traceback.

Comment: `vocabulary.default_factory = vocabulary.__len__`

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are assigning the result of the function when call. Try:

```
vocabulary.default_factory = vocabulary.__len__()  # Returns an int
vocabulary.default_factory = vocabulary.__len__    # The function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vocabulary = defaultdict(None)
vocabulary.default_factory = vocabulary.__len__()
```

You're setting `vocabulary`'s factory to the number zero here. So when it can't find the first element in `analyzed`, it's giving you zero, which of course doesn't have indexing capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

If the `defaultdict`'s `default_factory` is set to an int, such as `vocabulary.__len__()` (equivalent to `len(vocabulary)`), then the defaultdict tries to call that int with the given key, which will result in your error, `'int' object is not callable`.

Maybe you wanted the `default_factory` to be set to the method, `vocabulary.__len__`, rather than it's result?